# XQuery: Omitting empty elements during a transformation

Tags: xml, xquery

Currently I'm working on some XML transformations. It can happen that the input XML doesn't have certain values, which results in empty elements. So the output might look like:

```
<car>
  <category>Combi</category>
  <name>VW Passat</name>
  <age />
</car>
```

My question is if there is a global option or something similar to omit this empty elements such as `<age />`?

I could check within the transformation if a certain value is existing. Or I could use a Post-Processing to remove empty elements. But I have hope that there is a more elegant way to do it :-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that there are any serialization options in XQuery that will allow you to omit nilled elements in the output.

I would suggest just using a slightly modified identity which drops the nilled elements to post-process the output. Something like the following should work:

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare function local:remove-nilled($node as node()) as node()? {
    typeswitch($node)
        case document-node()
        return
            document {
                for $child in $node/node()
                return
                    local:remove-nilled($child)
            }

        case element()
        return
            if($node/node())then
                element { node-name($node) } {
                    $node/attribute(),
                    for $child in $node/node()
                    return
                        local:remove-nilled($child)
                }
            else()

        default
        return
            $node
};

local:remove-nilled(
    document {
        <car>
            <category>Combi</category>
            <name>VW Passat</name>
            <age />
        </car>
    }
)
```

Comment: can you please modify the function to get even xml tags with value